# Javascript error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript

On my site: csgowulfit.tk , you are able to withdraw cs-go items... In the withdraw section there is a recaptcha so no bots can withdraw... Upon completion of the recaptcha you are greated with:

```
Javascript error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I didn't know what to do so I opened console and saw the error the message followed:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (offers.js?v=106:249)
at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1)
at x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1)
```

"recaptcha__en.js" was next to the "Failed to load resource..."
I created the directory in my js folder and filled it with the code from:
https://gist.github.com/sekimura/e96c69be56e71940d8e9

And it still gives me: Javascript error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Your question is confusing, make it clearer

Comment: Add it in your string at the spots you want the newline? Looks pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: Not like that. chat("alert", "Minimum bet: " + m.minbet + " coin. <br /> Maximum bet: "

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you show what you have tried and add a [mcve] to your question. That way we are better able to help you. For more information see [ask].

Comment: What does `chat` do with the argument? Do you use some library that defines that function, or did you define it yourself (then please share the code)?

Answer (score 0):

`<br/>` is an html tag.
In Javascript, you can make a new line with `\n`

```
chat("alert",
  "Minimum bet: " + m.minbet + " coin.\n" +
  "Maximum bet: " + formatNum(MAX_BET) + " coins.\n" +
  "Bets per round: " + m.br + ".\n" +
  "Round time : " + m.accept + " seconds.\n" +
  "Chat delay: " + m.chat + " seconds. "
);
```